# How many hours it will take to transfer 500 gb of data from on premise SQL database to AWS S3 using AWS DMS t4 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-dms

How many hours  it will take to transfer 500 gb of data from on premise SQL database to AWS S3 using AWS DMS.

I want to use  t3 or t4 instances in AWS   DMS

Comment: There is no t4 instance type for AWS DMS.  Also, we can't possibly give you a concrete answer, since much depends on the database schema, and connectivity of the on prem database.

Answer (score 0):

as noted on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71486476/i-have-6-tb-of-on-premise-data-i-need-to-transfer-it-to-aws-s3-what-will-be-th/71494654#71494654), you do not need ec2 for data transfer. Just mount a disk locally with [S3 File Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html) service, it will be one of the easiest ways to do it.

Speed will depend on your network connection between you and AWS destination. You can test ping here to get some insight: https://cloudpingtest.com/aws

Comment: Do you mean [S3 File Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/file/) rather than API Gateway?

Comment: Yes, API Gateway is to host REST/Socket APIs and has payload limit of 10Mb. Your single upload "batch" would be limited by 10Mb and you would pay a lot more. You do not need any kind of compute service to transfer data. Don't think about anything like Lambda, Ec2, API Gateway etc. You just need networking & storage. That's it. File Gateway can mount local drive for you directly to drive in cloud or s3 bucket. Then you will pay for network + storage.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/pricing/?nc=sn&loc=3
https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

ingress traffic is free networking, so it won't charge for data upload. Download is paid though, starting at 0.09$/gb for  <10Tb/month